# Why can't I check my page speed on my webpage?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Every time I try to check my speed, I receive this error:

```
Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: Extension result empty. Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with https://www.partyextended.com/ Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit() before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5525:13) at http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:708:9 at Map.forEach (<anonymous>) at chromium.DevTools.Connection.dispatchMessage (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:707:76) at chromium.DevTools.Connection.onJsonMessage_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:689:65) at <anonymous>:1:40
```

What can I do?

Comment: Looks like something is taking too long to load on your page, it's causing the pagespeed insights to give up and fail.

Answer (score 1):

My comment was removed so let's try an answer.

The reason your site will not work with Page Speed Insights is that you have a script designed to attempt to protect your source code.

This script activates the debugger and pauses script execution, generating the following code:-

```
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
})
```

This pauses execution of JavaScript for Page Speed Insights and causes the timeout (as PSI interacts with the console to create it's data, your protection script pauses execution indefinitely).

The script does not offer any protection as you can simply block the request and reload the page so it all it does it cause your problems. (also if anyone is trying to crawl your site and extract data they will be doing it via cURL or similar so JS doesn't even matter at that point.)

However your legal notices script will ruin your Rankings as Google Bot will not crawl the page correctly, it also prevents you from running Page Speed Insights etc.

Finally the User Experience is affected by not being able to right click.

Whoever advised you to try to protect the code on your site has misled you into thinking this was a good idea, it will cause you hundreds of problems and offers no protection as stated previously.

The offending scripts is as follows, remove it and your site will work fine:-

[legalNotice.js](https://vaultcdn.electricapps.net/lib/legalNotice.js?shop=partyextended.myshopify.com&shop=partyextended.myshopify.com)